# Rails UJS with URL params issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

I have a basic working rails app where I rely a lot on URL params for displaying or not logic.
I was able to ajaxify it using UJS and link_to remote => true but when I click these links, the shown URL isn't updated (which makes sense) and other partials can't read the URL params

For example, in `index.html.erb` (before UJS so you can see how it works),

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% if params[:category] %><div class="row-fluid span6">
    <div class="span6">
      <%= render :partial => "buglist" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% if params[:id] %>
    <div class="span6">
      <%= render :partial => "bugdetails" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <% unless params[:category] or params[:id]%>
    <%= render :partial => "landingpage" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

1. My navbar has link_to for multiple :category, like this

   "top10", :action => "index", :category => catname) %>
2. If there is a params[:category] in the URL, I display a list on the left and when I click an ID in this list, it'll display the right DIV with
3. If there is no params, it'll render what I call the landing page (some kind of homepage)

This works good now but if I add remote => true to my navbar links, it'll work for the left div but the #3 (landing page) will always display because for some reason it won't see the URL params.  Also, since the shown URL is always the same, all my link_to_unless(params...) won't work.

With USJ:

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row-fluid span6" id="buglist"></div>
<div class="row-fluid span6" id="bugdetails"></div>
<div class="row-fluid id="landingpage"></div>
```

index.js.erb

```
<% if params[:category] %>
  $("#buglist").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'buglist')) %>");
<% end %>

<% if params[:id] %>
  $("#bugdetails").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bugdetails')) %>");
<% end %>

<% unless params[:category] or params[:id]%>
  $("#landingpage").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'landingpage')) %>");
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching functionality to ajax and not doing page reloads, you may wish to consider putting those url params as session variables instead.  That way you can update and show them as desired.

Comment: Would you have any link explaining how-to to suggest ?

I was also thinking about using PJAX (http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax) but I'll look at your suggestion first.